# AT&T assembly FPU, 1 divided by X (arg)

Tags: assembly, att, fpu

I'm trying to implement function in AT&T assembly which will return result of dividing 1 by X, where X is the param of type double, passed to the function from C (complete program is used to compute integral of 1/x function on specific range [Rectangle-based integration]) I had NO problems with doing it for cosinus function.
For this case the problem is that the result of integral is always -nan when I want to integrate this function with number of rectangles greater than 6, when I use below or equal to 6 the result is reasonable but not accurate enough. 
Parameteres like range begin and range end, and rectangle count (accuracy of integration) are passed from command line - argv table. Here's the code of assembly (AT&T syntax) implementation of function.

```
.data
result:
    .double 0.0

.globl onebyx
.type onebyx, @function

onebyx:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    FLDL 8(%ebp) # loading function arg
    FLD1    # loading constant 1 

    # should be: ST0 - 1; ST1 - function arg

    FDIVP %ST(1)  # dividing 1 by function arg

    fstl result

    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Standard calling convention passes back value on the FPU stack. You forgot to show your function prototype, but I am guessing it should be returning a `double`. As such, delete the `fstl result` and the `movl result, %eax`. PS: why are you using assembly for this?

Comment: Oh, he is leaving it on the stack... that's actually correct if he wants to return it.

Comment: lol @Jester I posted it and then removed the comment almost immediately. I didn't actually look to see what his real intent was until I hit enter, saw it and removed it.

Comment: However you are on the right track, since `fdiv` leaves the operand on the stack, and that's what's gonna overflow. I suggest using `fdivp`.

Comment: yep in this case `fdivp` is correct for this case and as you say remove the use of _EAX_ and `result`

Comment: gcc converts `double f(double x){return 1/x;}` into `fld1;
 fdivl 4(%esp);
 ret;}`

Comment: yes, function returns double. I did edit: removed instruction mov result, %eax and change fdiv to fdivp
@Jester - unniversity task :D

Comment: thank you guys! it's working now